# How to add a library to an existing Python distribution bundled with a program?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am a user of a program written in Python and have limited knowledge over the development side of Python. The problem I have is that under Windows, I got this error every now and then:

```
INFO - [Mar 03 09:00:41] GAE "GET https://inbox.google.com/" appid='someappid' SSLError('The read operation timed out',), retry...
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.1.21.66', 51549)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\python27.zip\SocketServer.py", line 595, in process_request_thread
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\proxylib.py", line 934, in finish_request
  File "proxy.py", line 761, in __init__
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\python27.zip\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\python27.zip\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\proxylib.py", line 2296, in handle_one_request
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\python27.zip\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in handle_one_request
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\proxylib.py", line 2327, in do_METHOD
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\proxylib.py", line 1031, in handle
  File "C:\goagent-3.2.3\local\proxylib.py", line 2327, in do_METHOD
  File "proxy.py", line 452, in handle
  File "proxy.py", line 452, in <genexpr>
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp1252
```

I've done some research and it seems the Python installation is missing libiconv. Now the program I am using is actually goagent (https://github.com/goagent/goagent). The distribution contains Python 2.7 in the form of python27.exe, python27.zip and several .py files seemingly purely to support the functionality of the program (proxy) - addto-startup.py, dnsproxy.py, goagent-gtk.py, proxy.py, proxylib.py. I did not install Python myself, and python is not directly executable under command line.

How do make this bundled Python load libiconv? Please also point me to the right place to download libiconv for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`I do not have enough points to comment hence writing in ANSWER section`

If you want libiconv , then you can follow install direction [here](http://gnu.org/software/libiconv/).
It seems to be a dependency on mingw64 compiler that may be part of distribution you are trying to download.

An alternate solution may be as follows,

Install plain python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
It will install most of the needed modules and its an MSI installer hence installation should be seamless.

Install pip for python from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)
Once pip is installed , you can install any needed modules simply by running following on command prompt or on windows power shell.
`pip install <module_namer>`
for eg.
`pip install pyaudio`
where pyaudio is a needed module.

Comment: I appreciate you replying to my question, but I did find these resources before I asked the question. I wasn't trying to use stackoverflow as Google. If I were asked the counterpart for Java, I could give a very detailed answer to setting up Java in Windows multiple ways. But I need Python.